# FindResource works, LoadBitmap doesn't, LoadImage from disk works

Tags: c, winapi, bitmap, cross-compiling, embedded-resource

I am trying to use [LoadBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to load an image from a [resource file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I've verified that the resource is linked correctly -- examining the final EXE with a hex editor shows that the bitmap is packed inside the EXE correctly.

I've also verified that the bitmap is valid -- using LoadImage with LR_LOADFROMFILE to load the bitmap from disk at runtime works fine and I see it appear when I add it to a gui element later.

I've verified that the ID that I use to access the resource is valid as well -- the FindResource function finds the resource and SizeofResource prints the exact expected number of bytes for the bitmap.

So I have a valid linked resource, a valid ID, and a loadable bitmap.

However, LoadBitmap returns NULL and so does LoadImage if I load from a resource instead of from disk. GetLastError returns 0.

Any ideas? Am I #defining RT_BITMAP in resource.rc correctly?

Thanks.

**resource.h**

```
#define     BMP_TEST_ID         2
```

**resource.rc**

```
#include "resource.h" // defines BMP_TEST_ID
#define     RT_BITMAP           2 

BMP_TEST_ID RT_BITMAP "TEST24.BMP"
```

**test.c**

```
#include <windows.h> // defines RT_BITMAP as MAKEINTRESOURCE(2)
#include "resource.h" // defines BMP_TEST_ID

HINSTANCE instance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
if (!instance) { /* handle error */ }

/* find a bitmap resource with the ID we want -- OK! */
HRSRC rsc = FindResource(instance, RT_BITMAP, MAKEINTRESOURCE(BMP_TEST_ID));
if (!rsc) { /* handle error */ }

/* prints the exact size of the found resource -- GIVES CORRECT OUTPUT */
printf("SizeofResource: %d\n", (int) SizeofResource(instance, rsc));

// ***** THIS BIT DOESN'T WORK *****
/* load bitmap resource -- FAIL! */
HBITMAP bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadBitmap(instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(BMP_TEST_ID));
if (!bitmap) { /* handle error */ }

/* load bitmap from file -- OK! */
HBITMAP bitmap2 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage (NULL, "TEST24.BMP", IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
if (!bitmap2) { /* handle error */ }
```

My compiler is amd64-mingw32msvc-gcc 4.6.3

Comment: Doesn't `LoadBitmap()` specifically look for resources of type `BITMAP`? I.e. shouldn't your decl be `BMP_TEST_ID BITMAP "TEST24.BMP"` ? See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380680(v=vs.85).aspx) on the `BITMAP` resource type.

Comment: @WhozCraig This works! Make it your answer and I'll accept it. Apparently you use RT_BITMAP in .c files but BITMAP in .rc files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not have to define `RT_BITMAP` at all. It is already defined through `winuser.h` to be included in your c/cpp files. And it turns out you don't need it in your resource file anyway.

The `BITMAP` resource type will properly assign the right resource type id for your bitmap file. Change your bitmap resource declaration to be:

```
BMP_TEST_ID BITMAP "TEST24.BMP"
```

And you should be good to go.