# cannot load resources in C++

Tags: c++, bitmap, resources

I have serious problems with resources loading. I made the .rc file and compiled it using windres with an output file "resource.o":

```
102  BITMAP  "slider_background.bmp"
```

The function main contains only the following code:

```
    if(LoadBitmap (GetModuleHandle(NULL),  MAKEINTRESOURCE (102)) == NULL);
      printf("error\n");
```

The final compilation was done using Mingw compiler:

```
g++ -o res_pokus main.o resource.o -mwindows
```

Unfortunately LodBitmap always returns NULL. When I use http://pedump.me/ for res_pokus.exe analysis, it seems that resource was loaded without problems (http://pedump.me/7758117ec301c21e49ecacecec82e2d7/#resources) - there is an correct ID and bitmap. I have tried different IDs or even disassemble LoadBitmap function and I am very desperate now.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried using `GetLastError()`  to see what error the `LoadBitmap` function is giving you?

Comment: A quick Google has also [got me this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501199/findresource-works-loadbitmap-doesnt-loadimage-from-disk-works).

Comment: @TonyTheLion `LoadBitmap` does not set LastError if it fails according to MSDN,  it just says that it will return NULL. There is no "To get extended error information, call GetLastError." text, which other functions on MSDN has.

Comment: @gurka Thanks, so it seems that I am senteced to disassembling for a very long time